Fermion Doubling theorem in 3D BZ
I am reading this review paper titled "Topological electronic bands on crystalline solids". On page 18, at the end of the proof for the Fermion doubling theorem, it is stated that the Chern number of a closed surface is simply the sum of chiralities of the Weyl nodes inside the surface. I have two questions.
First of all, I don't see why this is the case.
Also, what does it mean by the Chern number of a closed surface in general? Isn't a Chern number associated with a particular band? Are we summing up Chern numbers from all the bands calculated over the closed surface?

About your second question: Chern number is defined as the integral of the Berry curvature over the Brillouin Zone, which is a closed surface in general because the opposite edges of the BZ are the same line. For example, a square BZ is identical to a torus.

yes but we integrate Berry curvature of a particular band over the given surface, don't we?

The total Chern number is the sum of Chern numbers of all the filled bands.

That makes sense. Also, do you have any idea regarding the first question?
